# How do I get the remote IP-Address of clients connecting to a Rebol3 based server?

Tags: tcp, rebol, rebol3

I'm playing with [these basic TCP test scripts](http://www.rebol.com/article/0541.html) and would like to know: *"How to get the IP-Address of clients connecting to the server?"*

Any ideas? I tried to probe a client subport at the server-side, but it doesn't show the remote-ip.

Can someone give me hints on gathering that information. I know how it works within Rebol2, but I'm not familiar with the Rebol3 port model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain that information by calling QUERY on the client `port!`, which will return an object with `remote-ip` and `remote-port` fields.

Here's a simple example illustrating this, with a simple service that listens for connections on port 9090 and prints the address of clients connecting to that service:

```
rebol []

awake-server: func [event /local client info] [
    if event/type = 'accept [
        client: first event/port
        info: query client
        print ajoin ["Client connected: " info/remote-ip ":" info/remote-port]
        close client
    ]
]

serve: func [endpoint /local listen-port] [
    listen-port: open endpoint
    listen-port/awake: :awake-server
    wait listen-port
]

serve tcp://:9090
```

Answer (score 1):

The system/standard/net-info object includes two values - local-ip and remote-ip. I'm not sure whether that they get set though.

Give system/standard/net-info/remote-ip a try and if it contains none, I would suggest submitting a bug report.